# What kind approch is best to re-render(or reload) List class?

Tags: android, ios, listview, tabs, react-native

I'm developing the react-native APL using react-native-hackathon-starter(Tab controller) and list-detail screen control (Navigator)

```
render() {
return (
// Handle navigation between screen
<Navigator
// Default to list route
initialRoute={{name: 'list'}}
// Use FloatFromBottom transition between screens
configureScene={(route, routeStack) => 
 Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom} 
// Pass a route mapper functions
renderScene={RouteMapper}
　/>
　);
　}
}
```

Sign up, login processing is done at the account tab.

Login processing is implemented with Firebase authentication.

On the user tab, we acquire the current user id and display a list of logged-in user's information.

At the account tab, if the user logs out.

On the user tab, dose not reflect the logout and redisplay the previous user  information.

If the user logs in on a separate account tab, same dose not reflect the logout and redisplay the  previous user  information .

The problem is that the user tab's render does not occur after login in and logout.

I can retrieve the correct user by reloading the application and display it.

Two question

1. Can I control application reloading with React Native? such as CTRL-R on debbuger?
2. When login change processing was done with the account tab,
   Can I re-load the user tab? as described Hierarchy here,

   User Tab Class Hierarchy

   RootContainer (come from react-native-hackathon-starter)

   Nav  (come from react-native-hackathon-starter)

   List    (this class needed reloaded including constructor)

   Row

   Detail (When change tab clicked, list item is tapped, render is started)

How to re-render(or reload) List class when login or logou is occured?

Thanks

Shoji

Answer (score 0):

I've got the result Two questions.

1. Can I control application reloading with React Native? such as CTRL-R on debbuger?
2. When login change processing was done with the account tab, Can I re-load the user tab? as described Hierarchy here

I give up to add the CTRL-R function, because difficult for me.

I give up automatically re-render screen when another TAB condition change. I made re-load button for after change has occurred on another TAB.

Thanks,